# React: Why component's constructor is called only once?

Tags: reactjs

In the [following example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYVPBJ), when `Item 2` is clicked, `Second 1` is shown instead of `Second 2`. Why? How would you fix that?

---

```
var guid = 0;

class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    guid += 1;
    this.id = guid;
    console.log('ctor', this.id); // called only once with 1
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        {this.props.title} - {this.id}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2'];
    this.state = {
      activeItem: this.items[0]
    };
  }
  onItemClick(item) {
    this.setState({
      activeItem: item
    });
  }
  renderMenu() {
    return (
      <div className="menu">
        <div onClick={this.onItemClick.bind(this, 'Item 1')}>Item 1</div>
        <div onClick={this.onItemClick.bind(this, 'Item 2')}>Item 2</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.activeItem === 'Item 1') {
      return (
        <Content title="First" />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Content title="Second" />
      );
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderMenu()}
        {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

React's [reconciliation algorithm](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) assumes that without any information to the contrary, if a custom component appears in the same place on subsequent renders, it's the same component as before, so reuses the previous instance rather than creating a new one.

If you were to implement `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`, you would see that getting called instead.

> #### [Different Node Types](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#different-node-types)
>
> It is very unlikely that a `<Header>` element is going to generate a DOM that is going to look like what a `<Content>` would generate. Instead of spending time trying to match those two structures, React just re-builds the tree from scratch.
>
> As a corollary, if there is a `<Header>` element at the same position in two consecutive renders, you would expect to see a very similar structure and it is worth exploring it.
>
> #### [Custom Components](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#custom-components)
>
> We decided that the two custom components are the same. Since components are stateful, we cannot just use the new component and call it a day. React takes all the attributes from the new component and calls `component[Will/Did]ReceiveProps()` on the previous one.
>
> The previous component is now operational. Its `render()` method is called and the diff algorithm restarts with the new result and the previous result.

If you give each component [a unique `key` prop](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys), React can use the `key` change to infer that the component has actually been substituted and will create a new one from scratch, giving it the full component lifecycle.

---

```
  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.activeItem === 'Item 1') {
      return (
        <Content title="First" key="first" />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Content title="Second" key="second" />
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-log-lifecycle will print out explanations for each part of the lifecycle which might help understanding as well. Disclosure: I wrote that.

Comment: Adding the key prop solved this issue for me.