# Why is the component constructor getting called when I navigate back to a page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a android app using React-Native which has a large financial form. The way I have structured the app is that I make an API call to retrieve the form data on the main page which loads the form and I store it in `this.state.appForm`. The form is then segregated into seven different pages and presented to the user. I have created separate component for each of the pages.

```
      render(){
       var pages = []
       pages.push(<FirstPage key="Firstkey" appForm=this.state.appForm/>)
       pages.push(<SecondPage key="Secondkey" appForm=this.state.appForm/>)
       pages.push(<ThirdPage key="Thirdkey" appForm=this.state.appForm/>)
        .
        .
       pages.push(<SevenPage key="Sevenkey" appForm=this.state.appForm/>)  
       
        return(
        <NavigationBarComponent/> //contains back button, progressBar & save button
          <ScrollView>
             {pages[this.state.page]}
          </ScrollView>
        <ContinueButtonComponent/>
      )}
    
        onContinue() {
        if (!this.state.isValid) return;
        if (this.state.page == LAST_PAGE) {
          this.onSubmit();
         } else {
          this.setState({page: (this.state.page + 1)});
         }
        }
    
       onBackPress() {
        if (this.state.page>0){
          this.state.page--
          this.forceUpdate()
        }
       }
```

A pages array stores all the pages and I increment and decrement it to move ahead and back in the flow. Each component takes user input and directly updates the appForm.

*Question: Whenever I navigate back to any page (using `pages--`) the constructor of page I am landing on gets called again which again performs all the computations in `constructor` and `ComponentDidMount` again. How can to stop the constructor being called when I go back to a page?*

I checked answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074690/react-why-components-constructor-is-called-only-once) which says give each component a unique key prop but I am already doing that.

Any comments to improve the structure of the app will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the Navigator component? It is designed for this use case.

Comment: Yes. I use the navigator component for handling all the navigation in the app. Only the form is implemented this way. Maybe using navigator will fix this issue but will require lot of code changes. I wanted to understand what is causing this issue and why the unique key prop is not working.

Comment: Can you add code which you are using to navigate back to any of the previous page.

Comment: `onBackPress() {
    if (this.state.page>0){
      this.state.page-- ;
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
  }`

Comment: @Vijay If I use the Navigator component I will not be able to reuse the NavigationBar component which tracks progress in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be un-mounting and re-mounting the component so it's normal for it to be re-instantiated. You could only avoid this if the pages were rendered once and switched/transitioned, if you're using built in Navigator you can't get around it. Either way it's better to adjust how you're doing your logic - it should be in an action/store, not in the constructor/the component (which should be as "dumb" as possible).

Since your store should be a singleton instance it shouldn't change between pages so your action can be condition based - `dispatch(doActionIfNotDone)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using any store but I will try to move the logic to main page. If the component goes out of view it will be automatically be unmounted - is my understanding correct?

Comment: Np, yep the Navigator will unmount pages going out of view after the transition