# Item prepended to FlatList data appears at bottom of list

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have this FlatList Component in my React Native app that I'm trying to prepend an item to:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.comments}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  extraData={this.state}
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
    <CardComment navigate={this.props.navigation.navigate} report={item.reply}/>
  )}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
/>
```

I'm trying to update the list and put a new item on the top of the current comments. After a successful request, this is what I'm doing on my fetch:

```
.then((r) => {
  this.setState({
    refreshing: false,
    loadingComments: false,
    comments: [
      {reply: r},
      ...comments,
    ],
  });
});
```

Even though I'm adding the new element to the start of the `comments` list, it still appears at the bottom of the `FlatList` when it renders. Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: As the asker eventually realised, this is actually the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/45199769/1709587 - you need to provide a `key` prop when rendering an array of items. Note that, given the lack of `key` on `<CardComment ...>` above, this code should have thrown a warning saying *VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key property on each item or provide a cu...*. That was the clue you missed!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
const comments = this.state.comments.slice();
comments.unshift({ reply: 'Reply Q' });
this.setState({ comments: comments});
```

And this will trigger a refresh.

The following shows how this solves your problem... https://snack.expo.io/BkAi7StY-

Comment: hey, thanks but that doesnt work :(
btw, as stated on the reacts documentation, you shouldnt modify state directly. instead you should use setState.

Comment: Ah ok, I re-read your question and realised you were asking about the actual refreshing process too. Updating the answer - tried and tested :)

Comment: And btw, at no point did I modify state directly...I used setState...

Comment: I'll explain what I mean: If you misunderstood the first line as setting state, it's called destructuring of a variable and is equivalent to const comments=this.state.comments. Did you see how my answer solves your problem? If not I'm happy to share a working example with you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time. I really appreciate.
I ended up not using setState anymore bcs i changed to redux and now it's working. But still, i need to clean up the array, and dispatch a new array with the new "reply" to see the changes on the FlatList.

Comment: and the setState thing, i misread when you wrote "this.setState={ comments: comments };" and I read "this.state.comments = comments". sorry

Comment: No probs. Updated my answer with a working code example to show how it solves both the ordering and the update problem.

Comment: About needing to clean up the array - do try something similar to what I have done - using const and slicing the comments array to create a new array. That triggers a re-render. See my example :)

Comment: Given that I have a proven answer to your original question, it would be great if you could accept my answer...

Comment: I accepted it. It might work with someone else though.

Comment: btw, this is what actually solved my problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199769/react-components-state-renders-strangely-with-unshift-but-normal-with-push?rq=1

Comment: Even there though the crux of the matter is that slice() and similar methods return an entirely new object while unshift operates on the same object and only returns an index. I still think my solution should solve your issue, unless there are details that you haven't gone into. It certainly works in the Expo Snack demo (which I've improved slightly too...)

Comment: -1; the asker specified that he was already calling setState with a new array with the element to add at the start. Showing a slightly different way of doing that (with `.slice()` and `.unshift` instead of an array literal with the spread operator) doesn't help anybody and couldn't possibly have solved the asker's problem. Going on to nag the asker in the comments into accepting your "proven" fix (that doesn't actually work) is especially poor form.

Comment: Your point about using the key is the best answer (as I have since discovered as I gained experience), but I simply did my best to help the user with my knowledge at the time, and I was merely suggesting the user accept an answer that worked - and I assure you it DID produce the correct behaviour at the time - it's unfair to discredit that. Calling my comments nagging strikes me as wholly unnecessary. Fair enough with the downvote but I can't accept the poor form comments without response...

Answer (score 0):

So I found out some workaround while I can't seem to find the answer to my question. I save my previous comments array, setState to clean the array, so that I can clean the whole FlatList component. Then, on the callback of the first setState, I append the new element to the beginning of the first array.

```
    comments = this.state.comments;
    this.setState({comments:[]}, function(){
      this.setState({
        comments: [
          {reply: r},
          ...comments,
        ],
        loadingComments: false,
      });
    });
```

Still, If anyone has a better solution or knows the solution for my problem, let me know please. :)

UPDATE:
this is what actually solved my problem: [React Component's state renders strangely with .unshift(), but normal with .push()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199769/react-components-state-renders-strangely-with-unshift-but-normal-with-push?rq=1)