# Render method does not re-render element initialized in the constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, ecmascript-6, render

I am new to react and was experimenting when I noticed a behavior with controlled form elements. I have a controlled input element whose value is bound to the state of the parent component and its onChange handler takes the typed value from the user and updates the state. So every-time, the user types something, the input value reflects the change. This is the desirable effect. It works great when the input is created in the render function. But in case , the input is initialized through a class variable which is set in the constructor, the same input does not update its value when state changes. The only difference being where the input element is initialized first. What would cause such a behavior?
Any help is appreciated!

Here is an example of what code that causes the faulty behavior might look like:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      val : '',
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.input = (
    <input type="text" 
           onChange={this.handleChange } 
           value={this.state.val} />
    );
  }
  
  handleChange(e){
   this.setState({val:e.target.value});
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">  
        { this.input ? this.input : null }                
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This question will help you to understand why it's acting like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074690/react-why-components-constructor-is-called-only-once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor for a React component is called only before it is mounted.
If you define some variable in constructor, it will store its value not reference and will not be re render again.

Refer [react constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

The functions which are called on props/state change are

- componentWillReceiveProps()
- shouldComponentUpdate()
- componentWillUpdate()
- render()
- componentDidUpdate()

and in case you want to store the reference of any element, you can use **refs**.

```
render() {
  <input type="text" 
    onChange={this.handleChange } 
    value={this.state.val}
    ref={ ele => (this.input = ele)} 
  />
}
```

read more about [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 3):

You have stored (or cached) your input into a variable outside of the render. So when your component updates, it just renders the cached version of your input again and again.

You need to define `this.input` as a function returning the `<input>`, like this:

```
this.input = () => (
    <input type="text" 
       onChange={this.handleChange } 
       value={this.state.val} />
);
```

And call `this.input()` in the render. Now, the input will be updated at each render.

However, if what you want is just to create a reference to the input (`this.input`), **I would rather recommend to make this reference inside the render, by using [the special prop `ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)**:

```
render() {
  <input type="text" 
    onChange={this.handleChange } 
    value={this.state.val}
    ref={input => (this.input = input)}  // the magic happens here
  />
}
```

In doing so, you don't need to define `this.input` as a function in your constructor.