# react does not re render on props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state-management

here is my `render` method of `FormEl` component.

```
return <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.clicked}>click to add 1 input</button>
            <Inputs count={this.state.childcount}/>
        </div>
```

in `clicked` method I update the `childcount` by 1 using `setState`

this is the `Inputs` class

```
class Inputs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("Input constructor is running.");
        this.state = {value: '', p: "p", count: props.count};
    }

    render() {
        let c = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
            c.push(
                <div key={"id-" + (i * 10)}>
                    <input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.value}/>
                    <p> {this.state.p}</p>
                </div>);
        }
        return <div>
            {c}
        </div>;
    }
}
```

But, when I update the `childcount` in `clicked`, I can see `FormEl` is re-rendered, `count` in `<Inputs..` is increased accordingly. But it does not call `constructor` of `Inputs` other than first (page loading) time.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Calling `setState()` will update the component i.e `render()` will be called. That doesnot mean the whole component will be newly created i.e calling the `constructor`

Comment: Duplication of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29074980/2404452

Comment: You need to use `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: @Abinthaha `componentWillReceiveProps()` will be deprecated soon. So, it is not advisable to use that. He has to use `componentDidUpdate()` instead

Comment: Yeah. It will be deprecated soon. But if you are working on react version less than 16, you can use it then

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use this.props.count instead.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.props.count; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, constructor method of `Inputs` component will be called only once after it gets mounted. It'll never be called again. So, what you can do is have [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) method in `Inputs` component and setState when the incoming `count` prop is different from your present state count.

Or else, you can directly use `this.props.count` in the `for` as suggested by [@lsa4299](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52200326/3607191)

Answer (score 0):

constructor is meant to be only called once, so you only might set an initial state there.

In fact as you are not modifying the state from Inputs class, you do not need any state at all. You can declare const value=""; const p="p"; on the top of your render method. And just use this.props.count instead of this.state.count

You can remove the constructor in that case.

In case you later on modify the behavior of your Component and need to set the state depending on new props (not current case) you might want to check getDerivedStateFromProps method.