# Reactjs - Why doesn't my MaterialUI Datatable refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So currently I'm trying to render a `DataTable` component. If I click on a button `Users`, it should render a table of my `Users`. When I click on the button `Devices`, it should render a table of my `Devices`. However, for some reason, it will only render the datatable of whichever one I click first.

E.g. if I click `Devices`, it will render my `Devices` table. Now, when I try to navigate to my `Users` by clicking on the `Users` button, it'll still display my `Devices` datatable.

I maintain a state inside `DataTable` and I'm updating the state with props that I pass into it. Is there a design flaw that I made that causes my `DataTable` to not render the correct data?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Upon some debugging, it seems the state isn't being updated when I click on the `Users` button

Comment: Too many reasons can be here. Could you provide some code of these components, please?

Answer (score 1):

Reading this [React: Why component's constructor is called only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074690/react-why-components-constructor-is-called-only-once) solved my problem.

TLDR: Rendering the same component will not refresh the component. To overcome this, I needed to introduce a `key` prop.