# React global snackbar component can only be called once

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I'm a newbie, but after two months of studying, I think maybe I'm in a deep state of understanding REACT.
Well, my problem is that after I build a global snackbar using context, it can be called successfully, but puzzlingly it will not be displayed in the next calls. I didn't post the provider code because with only 3 lines it shouldn't be the problem

There is CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/small-lake-osxkxw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
When you click in sequence or repeatedly, it does not work properly.

This is file of render snackbar component

```
import useSnackbar from "./useSnackbar";
import { Alert, Slide, Snackbar } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

export const GlobalSnackbar = () => {
    const { message, severity, duration } = useSnackbar();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
    
    const handleClose = (e, reason) => {
        if (reason === "clickaway") {
            return;
        }
        setOpen(false);
    };
    if (message && severity) {
        return (
            <Snackbar key={message} anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'center' }} autoHideDuration={duration}
            open={open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Slide}>
            <Alert severity={severity} variant="filled" onClose={handleClose}>{message}</Alert>
        </Snackbar>
        );
    } else {
        return ;
    }
}
```

This is Context 2 file

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { createContext } from "react";

const DURATION = 3000;
const SnackContext = createContext({
    message: '',
    severity: '',
    duration: DURATION,
    callSnack: () => {},
});

export function SnackProvider({children}){
    const duration = DURATION;
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [severity, setSeverity] = useState('');

    const callSnackbar = (message, severity) => {
        setMessage(message);
        setSeverity(severity);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            setMessage('');
            setSeverity('');
        },duration);
    };

    return (
        <SnackContext.Provider value={{message, severity, duration, callSnackbar}}>{children}</SnackContext.Provider>
    );
}
export default SnackContext;
```

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import SnackContext from "./SnackContext";

const useSnackbar = () => useContext(SnackContext);
export default useSnackbar;
```

I call it like this.

```
export default function Test(){
   let { callSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
   
   const handle = () => {
    callSnackbar("Good", "success");
   };
   
   return (
   <button onClick={handle}>Call Snackbar</button>
   );
}
```

I initially guessed that maybe I should use LET instead of CONST, but that didn't work. I learned about the REACT rendering pattern when I was looking for an answer [React: Why component's constructor is called only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074690/react-why-components-constructor-is-called-only-once) , so I added KEY to the rendering component, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone help me? I think I may have entered a blind spot of knowledge that I have not yet learned

Comment: Needless to say, did you wrap the application with the `<SnackProvider />`?

Comment: Of course, I have successfully called it. I just didn't post those 3 lines of code since it wasn't the key to this problem.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to provide a minimal reproducible example on CodeSandbox? That way people can help you with your problem easier :)

Comment: I'm very sorry I'm so late in replying. I have registered an account and created the simplest case, which fortunately expresses my problem perfectly.

Comment: @HappyKoala, In the example you provided it seems like the snackbar working fine isn't it?

Comment: Actually, no, wait a few seconds to try to repeat the click. And try a few times. It will not work.

Comment: @HappyKoala, You need to pass down the state values of `open` and `setOpen` from parent component as you have the open snackbar button in the parent component. Example https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-scott-jxwdf1

Comment: @ManirajMurugan  According to this approach, the fact is that Context doesn't do much, right? Because the same functionality can be achieved by adding the MESSAGE and SEVERITY variables, and it is much more concise. But I am not sure which way the production standard works?

Comment: Or is it more appropriate to use HOC at this point?

Comment: @HappyKoala, It depends on your application. Here you have included only the button and onclick of that snackbar displays. If you need to use some app level global variables then you can go with context.

Comment: Thank you @ManirajMurugan,  I should pass the OPEN status value. And I just tested it and think CONTEXT has the widest applicability. It will not be called in callbacks if use components. What I did was to add the OPEN state value to SnackbarContext and then add one more OPEN variable per call so they should work fine.