# React js component update

Tags: reactjs, react-state

```
import React from 'react'
class Clock extends React. Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.State={
            date: new Date()
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <>
            <h1>{this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>
            </>
        )
    }
}
export default Clock;

import Clock from './Clock';
const root=ReactDOM.createRoot(document. getElementById("root"));
const clock=()=> {
    console.log("hi");
    root.render(<Clock/>)
}
setInterval(() => {
    clock();
}, 1000);
```

after every second we are calling the clock function in index.js, so it means after every second rendering the element also, but it is not updating in the browser after every second.  In the console "hi" is printing which means my clock function is running after every second.
What I am missing in the concept?

Comment: Your clock is not updating because the `new Date()` part is executed only once and not every time the component is rendered. I think that a better approach would be to manage the timer inside the component and not from the outside.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074690/react-why-components-constructor-is-called-only-once This will answer your question. Eventually, the child component's `state` will never change.

Comment: Have a look at this code, the replicate of yours, check the console how the state remains the same https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-kalam-mfxptx?file=/src/Clock.js

Answer (score 0):

React changes the rendering only if the state changes.
So to change the state you have to set it.
You can try this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ date: new Date() })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `props` from the parent component to the child component

Clock.js

```
import React from "react";
class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>{this.props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default Clock;
```

index.js file

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import Clock from "./Clock";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

setInterval(() => {
  root.render(<Clock date={new Date()} />);
}, 1000);
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-props-to-child-fo47ic

Comment: I know this one. My doubt is I am calling clock function after every one second i.e root.render() after every one second then why it is not updating